# Change scale of circles on Scatter Plot in Analytics Cloud

Tags: analytics-cloud

I have a scatter plot widget on a dashboard.

The circle area is too big - is there any way I can change this? I still want to have area as a measure, but need the circles to be much smaller.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point in time, this is impossible and you would need to change the size of your widget to accommodate

Answer (score 1):

The size of the circles is dependant on data within the measure, I haven't seen how this can be independently changed, as it is relative.